# Ruby CSV Parsing Memory Allocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, memory, out-of-memory

I've recently run into an issue interacting with large CSV files in Ruby. I'm sure the obvious solution is to host this data in a database instead of a file like this, but nonetheless, I'd like to find the root of my problem.

The data that I am interacting with isn't overly large - about 43M data points. The dimensions are 8760x5000. I really need to read this whole CSV file in so I can perform some mapping operations on it and then dump it out to a new file.

I've tried both:

```
CSV.foreach("file") do |row|    
    master_arr << row
end
```

and

```
master_arr = CSV.read("file")
```

Both of these options trigger a memory allocation error - stating there is not enough memory allocated. The error typically looks something like:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1798:in `gets': failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1798:in `block in shift'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1796:in `loop'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1796:in `shift'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1738:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1122:in `block in foreach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1273:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1121:in `foreach'
        from compilation.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure why this is an issue. The CSV file is around 600MB and as I watch resources of my machine, RAM consumption grows only by about 1GB prior to the failure. During this time, I still have about 10GB of available RAM.

If I create an array of the same size and populate it with random data:

```
arr1 = Array.new(8760){|i| i+0.111111111111}
arr2 = Array.new(5000){arr1}
```

there is no issue storing it in memory but if try to write it to a CSV file, I receive a memory allocation error. I went through the CSV.rb file but can't seem to find anything that would cause this.

The strange thing is that this works:

```
for i in 0..4999
    CSV.foreach("file") do |row|
        master << row
        break if master_arr.length > 3000
    end
end
```

but if I try to split the file into two, this does not work:

```
CSV.foreach("file_1_2") do |row|    
    master_arr << row
end

CSV.foreach("file_2_2") do |row_1|  
    master_arr << row_1
end
```

It's like these objects aren't being released from memory but I don't understand exactly what is going on. Like I said, I know this is a large file and it's not the best option, but this is a one-time solution and I have the available resources that it should be no problem.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit Ruby? Are you sure it's only 1GB?

Comment: Well... This is pretty embarrassing but that was in fact the issue. I guess when I used the packaged installer for Rails, it came with a 32-bit instance. Can't believe I didn't even think of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's commonly the case that 32-bit programs are subject to much stricter memory limits than 64-bit ones, and 32-bit Ruby is not able to allocate as much memory as the 64-bit version.

If you can check that your installation is the correct version, and if not, update to the right one. `ruby -v` usually tells you which one you're using.